# how to install the fedora supplemental wallpapers?

Tags: fedora

In [this blog post](http://karl-tux-stadt.de/ktuxs/?p=4744) we can see the list of Fedora 22 supplemental wallpapers. I've been searching for a while now, but I can't find how to install them on my fedora 22 system. [This post](http://fedoramagazine.org/photographers-submit-a-wallpaper-for-fedora-now/) gives the package name as it was for Fedora 20. Then I searched:

```
dnf search backgrounds-extras-gnome
```

And I got the names for many past versions, up to F21:

```
f21-backgrounds-extras-gnome.noarch : Extra F21 Wallpapers for Gnome and Cinnamon
verne-backgrounds-extras-gnome.noarch : Extra Verne Wallpapers for Gnome
laughlin-backgrounds-extras-gnome.noarch : Extra Laughlin Wallpapers for Gnome
heisenbug-backgrounds-extras-gnome.noarch : Extra Heisenbug Wallpapers for Gnome and Cinnamon
spherical-cow-backgrounds-extras-gnome.noarch : Extra Spherical Cow Wallpapers for Gnome
schroedinger-cat-backgrounds-extras-gnome.noarch : Extra Schrödinger's Cat Wallpapers for Gnome and Cinnamon
```

But I have no idea how to get the F22 ones.

Which is the relevant package name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any f22-backgrounds-extras package listed [here](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/i386/os/Packages/f/) or [here](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/x86_64/os/Packages/f/).

For now I suppose you can simply download them all from [nuancier](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/nuancier/results/3/) directly.